# Angular2 button not disabled when the form is initialized on IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, typescript, primeng

I am using Angular2 and PrimeNg to create a form.. There is a button that needs to be disabled when the form is not dirty or when it is invalid. All the things work well on Chrome but not on IE11. Here is the code ... the Modify button is not disabled as expected.

```
<button pButton type="submit" icon="fa-pencil" (click)="modify()"
[disabled]="!form.dirty || form.invalid || 
disableModifyButton" disabled="true" label="Modify"></button>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: have you tried `<button pButton [disabled]="true">`? note the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

`disabled` only have one attribute value is `disabled`, so try this

```
[disabled]="(!form.dirty || form.invalid || disableModifyButton) ? 'disabled' : null"
```

Comment: thanks! But this doesn't solve my issue. Actually the button is not disabled when the form is loaded but it is disabled when the form is invalid. I want the button to be disabled when the form is initialized.

Comment: `[disabled]="expression"` works fine for `Boolean` and truthy/falsy values in angular 2. Something else is going on.

Comment: Agree, I missed this